# Quando il verbo "mettere" è riflessivo?

Tags: grammar

"Stamattina Laura ha messo un bellessimo vestito rosso". Non sarebbe stato "Laura si é messa un bellissimo vestito" o qui il verbo "mettere" non è riflessivo perché ha un oggetto, quindi la prima frase è corretta?

Comment: bellessimo -> bellissimo; é -> è

Answer (score 2):

Nel caso di vestiti o altri oggetti da portare sulla persona, *mettere* usato in forma non riflessiva equivale a "far indossare", "far portare":

- mettere gli occhiali;
- mettere la gonna;

Questo ovviamente a meno che non vi sia un complemento di luogo:

- mettere gli occhiali sul comodino;
- mettere la gonna nell'armadio;

Nel caso del significato di indossare, è solitamente sottinteso che il soggetto di chi compie l'azione sia la stessa persona a/su cui l'oggetto o indumento sarà *messo*:

- vado a mettere gli occhiali;
- ho deciso di mettere la gonna;

Non è però sempre il caso:

- la mamma mi ha messo il cappello;
- Francesco, mettile l'anello;

Da qui la forma riflessiva (più frequente<sup>[1]</sup>), che ha valore di "mettere a sé stessi":

- mettersi gli occhiali;
- mettersi la gonna;

Tale forma è più chiara di "indossare", poiché indica l'azione vera e propria; "indossare", infatti, può avere un duplice significato: compiere l'azione di indossare ("indosso la giacca ed esco"), o l'avere un indumento indosso ("indosso la giacca da stamattina").

<sup>[1]: [Treccani: *méttere*](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mettere/), **(d)**</sup>